# How to assign a weight for classifiers when using weighted majority voting?

Tags: ensemble-modeling, ensemble-learning, ensemble

I am trying to apply weighted majority voting on an ensemble as a combiner method. I read different papers and articles, however, I am still a bit lost on:

1. How the weighted majority voting works
2. How to assign a weight for every ensemble base classifiers when using weighted majority voting.

Answer (score 1):

You can test each base classifier on a hold-out dataset and come up with a performance metric say accuracy for each model. You can then use each model's accuracy as a weight when combining predictions in the ensemble.

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/combine-predictions-for-ensemble-learning/) is a useful article.